# Change Visual Studio 2015's dark theme's TypeScript color scheme

Tags: typescript, themes, visual-studio-2015

If you're using Visual Studio 2015 + Dark Theme + TypeScript, you'd probably notice that the property of a class gets rendered with a black font. The black font on top of a very dark gray background is nearly unreadable. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

It appears identifiers also get rendered with a black font.

I've looked under Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors for a way to change this but not having any luck.

Is anyone else using this combination?
What is the best solution for making the .ts file more readable with the dark theme? Do I need to just hack whatever the theme file is (no idea how to do that,  yet, at this point).

Thanks,
Jayson

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem, too. I upgraded my installation of TypeScript to 1.8.6 from [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links), choosing the Visual Studio 2015 option. Then I restarted the IDE and everything looked wonderful. Hope this helps for anyone who likes the dark theme!

Comment: Restarting the IDE fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you change themes, You just reset visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately(IMO) VS2015 really changed a lot of their syntax coloring and now it looks ugly.

You can create your own themes or download them from https://studiostyl.es

Tools > Import and Export Settings > (Backup your settings) > Browse for your theme file.

You can also edit the pre-existing themes manually.

Comment: Thanks Aller. I actually don't mind most of the coloring except for this black-font-on-dark-background mess with typescript. I've checked out studiostyl.es before but didn't seem like they has VS2015 styles; unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue and what solved is a reboot of the system.

Every time when I go from light theme to dark theme the text stays opposite and vice versa untill reboot is done.

It didn't require me to update anything. Just a reboot when I change the theme.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's having this issue (since I've just installed vs2015 and seems still persisting) just solved it installing the latest update available for ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49959)

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to fix this. But, first, here are some background that sort of lead me to believe that this was more "solvable" that I initially thought.

I use VS2015 on multiple computers: one on my surface book (a Win10 machine) and on my work machine (a Win7 machine). On both VS instances, I'm logged in with the same profile account, therefore, by default, settings (including the selected theme) are synchronized.

I noticed that .ts files were rendering just fine on my work machine but not on my laptop. At first, I turned of synchronization so I can keep my laptop using the Light theme, while my work machine used the Dark theme.

All of this made me wonder if there were some settings from my Win7/VS instance that wasn't playing nice with my Win10/VS instance. So,..

I reset my settings by going to Tools -> Import and Export Settings and chose to Reset all settings. I chose not to back up my settings, but that's up to you if you're following along with this.

I chose an environment. The first one I chose was the C# Development environment, but that still had the same issue. I then performed the reset again, and this time chose the Web Development environment. And voila, by choosing the Web Development environment, TypeScript is now looking great in the Dark theme.

Update 12/11/2015.
Just a screenshot of my environment (you can see in the background the correctly rendered identifiers, now)
[image]

Comment: This did not work for me.  It is still black on almost-black.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I know how much of a pain it is. Just to clarify a few things, you did 1) unsynchronized your settings first (Tools -> Options -> Synchronized Settings), and then 2) reset your environment to default settings and 3) choosing the Web Development environment?

Comment: Also, I just want to provide my machine/vs settings so we're comparing the same thing:

From winver: Version 1511 Build 10586.29
From vs:
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1)   14.1.11120.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1)
ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.30624.0
(had to trim, but wanted to show the updated ASP.NET tooling)

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript 1.8 beta seems to have corrected the black identifiers on dark theme.

[image: TypeScript Version in VS]

[image: Light colored identifiers in VS]

Answer (score 0):

Normally this happens when you change your theme. If you change theme from Light to Dark or Blue to Dark, you may have experience this black letters in black background.

You may have similar experience if you change theme from Dark to Light or Blue, then you may have experience of white letters in white background.

**Resolution: Just Restart Visual Studio IDE.**